# ChartJS, updating chart type does not update xAxis properly

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am having problems updating the chart type from Bar => Line and Line => Bar. The xAxis does not update the starting/end positions of the ticks properly causing the chart to either get cut off on left/right opposite (see images below)

I am using this code to update the chart type. It grabs old config, destroys old chart, creates new one from old config.

```
var myChart = window.myChart;
myChart.config.type = 'bar';
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var cfg = Object.create(myChart.config);
myChart.destroy();
window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
```

In this example, I create the initial chart as a bar chart. I then change it to to line chart but the line chart does not start all the way at the left side now.

(Sorry for links, cant upload images because of reputation)

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49397342/55719410-2a562580-59cc-11e9-8a1e-f03417a24f8d.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49397342/55719420-2de9ac80-59cc-11e9-92ec-eeb9dcaf8181.png

When I start with a line chart, the opposite happens. The initial line chart is ok, but the bar chart now gets cut off.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49397342/55719740-f9c2bb80-59cc-11e9-8a0c-efdadc1afdd3.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49397342/55719742-fb8c7f00-59cc-11e9-9782-56a6cc982de6.png

This is my configuration, you can click the button to see problem. I've been digging through everything to find a solution online but wasn't able to find anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Start with Bar, change to Line. (Line starts in wrong position)
https://jsfiddle.net/30gkjb5z/2

Start with Line, change to Bar. (Bar gets cut off)
https://jsfiddle.net/qoyr1m6v/

Comment: I don't see any cut off in your fiddle

Comment: @TowkirAhmed Thanks you for pointing that out! I added another fiddle with second example. There are two scenarios, [1] start with bar, change to line [2] start with line, change to bar.

Comment: now I see, check the answer. accept and upvote it if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to destroy the chart and create one, simply create another on the same canvas with the desired option, `bar` or `line`

From `bar` to `line`:

```js
var dataset = {
  "labels": [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ],
  "datasets": [{
      "label": "Impressions",
      "data": [
        76422672,
        686284176,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "yAxisID": "impressions"
    },
    {
      "label": "Actions",
      "data": [
        18,
        198,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.3)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "yAxisID": "actions"
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  "title": {
    "display": true,
    "text": "My Chart"
  },
  "maintainAspectRatio": false,
  "responsive": true,
  "scales": {
    "yAxes": [{
        "scaleLabel": {
          "display": true,
          "labelString": "Impressions",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        },
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        },
        "position": "left",
        "id": "impressions"
      },
      {
        "scaleLabel": {
          "display": true,
          "labelString": "Actions",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        },
        "gridLines": {
          "display": false,
          "offsetGridLines": true
        },
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        },
        "position": "right",
        "id": "actions"
      }
    ],
    "xAxes": [{
      "ticks": {
        "display": true,
        "beginAtZero": true
      },
      "scaleLabel": {
        "display": true,
        "labelString": "Day",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
      },
      "gridLines": {
        "color": "rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.30)",
        "offsetGridLines": true
      }
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: dataset,
  options: options
});

var button = document.getElementById("changeChartType");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // here is your trick, change the type to 'bar' with same other options;
  window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataset,
    options: options
  });
});
```

```css
.myChartContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.myChartContainer canvas {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartContainer">
  <canvas id="myChart" style="min-height: 300px"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="changeChartType">
Change Chart Type
</button>
```

And from `line` to `bar`:

```js
var dataset = {
  "labels": [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ],
  "datasets": [{
      "label": "Impressions",
      "data": [
        76422672,
        686284176,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "yAxisID": "impressions"
    },
    {
      "label": "Actions",
      "data": [
        18,
        198,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.3)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "yAxisID": "actions"
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  "title": {
    "display": true,
    "text": "My Chart"
  },
  "maintainAspectRatio": false,
  "responsive": true,
  "scales": {
    "yAxes": [{
        "scaleLabel": {
          "display": true,
          "labelString": "Impressions",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        },
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        },
        "position": "left",
        "id": "impressions"
      },
      {
        "scaleLabel": {
          "display": true,
          "labelString": "Actions",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        },
        "gridLines": {
          "display": false,
          "offsetGridLines": true
        },
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        },
        "position": "right",
        "id": "actions"
      }
    ],
    "xAxes": [{
      "ticks": {
        "display": true,
        "beginAtZero": true
      },
      "scaleLabel": {
        "display": true,
        "labelString": "Day",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
      },
      "gridLines": {
        "color": "rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.30)",
        "offsetGridLines": true
      }
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: dataset,
  options: options
});

var button = document.getElementById("changeChartType");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // and here, change to type: 'line' 
  window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: dataset,
    options: options
  });
});
```

```css
.myChartContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.myChartContainer canvas {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartContainer">
  <canvas id="myChart" style="min-height: 300px"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="changeChartType">
Change Chart Type
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like its a problem with some value in the old config grabbed using myChart.config, when using original config it works fine. Wish I know which value was breaking it, that way I would not have to rebuild other dynamic options already added.

Comment: You're right, I tried to do the same too, instead of re-creating the entire chart, toggling a specific option would be much convenient. however there is a problem while changing the chart type from or to bar, here is a link : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#bar-controller
otherwise, we could simply do `window.myChart.controller.config.type = 'line';` and then `window.myChart.update();` to update the chart

Comment: BTW, your values are totally fine. it's just how bar and line chart works, each time they take a special value from the data set while calculating the placement of bars or lines. the link on the above comment describes that.